# Genus of projective curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, plane-curves

I have the projective curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by
\begin{align}
F(X,Y,Z)=Y^2 Z^2-X^4-Y^4.
\end{align}
I want to calculate the genus of the curve. My approach would be to calculate the partial derivatives and use the
multiplicities $r_i$ of the singular points in the formula
\begin{align}
g(F)=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}-\sum_i \frac{(r_i-1) r_i}{2}.
\end{align}
I get $DF(X,Y,Z)=(4X^3,2YZ^2-4Z^3,2Y^2Z)$, and I get the singular point polynomials $X^3, Z^2(Y-2Z),Y^2Z$. Is the next step to calculate $r_i$ by the intersection number between the curve $F$ and the singular point polynomials? Or do I need to dehomogenize $F$ to get the tangents to intersection between the tangents? Or do I need another approach for the $r_i$?

Comment: there is only one singular point [0:0:1] with multiplicity 2. Just taking the common zero point of DF and F.

Comment: I believe you made a mistake when computing the differential